# XCode Storyboard is empty and changes not visible on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a serious problem on XCode. I can not see my storyboards correctly even they are full of elements. Sometimes elements are visible after I restart the XCode but later it happens again. Another issue is that even I change fonts or change locations of elements its not visible on storyboard until I restart the XCode.

XCode version is: 8.2.1 (8C1002)

You can see in the image that storyboard is transparent.

[image]

Comment: Did you merge code with someone else and your storyboard file got corrupt? Usually when it won't show it means the XML has some invalid or duplicate values. Try restarting also. Worth a shot.

Comment: Yest I merged but restarting doesn't help. How to fix corrupted XML if so?

Comment: Look at your git merge and see what xml elements were added or changed. If you both created new elements in the storyboard or controllers they might have got the same ID. You have to manually go back before the merge and figure out how to merge it by hand correctly. git tries to make merging easy but this one you have to do very carefully.